# Sincronizar hora de javascript-angular con la hora del servidor

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, date

Buenas, tengo una web con base php y gestiona la parte de cliente con angular. Mi problema es que cuando alguien entra con la hora cambiada a la de España o zona horaria diferente la función Date de javascript no me vale ya que los countdown no funcionan bien, angulardate no muestra bien la fecha, por ejemplo si tengo que la fecha es el 18/06/2017 18:00, si cambio de zona horaria mi reloj a GTM+2 se cambia a 18/06/2017 19:00.

Habría alguna forma de poder forzar a Date de javascript a usar de referencia la hora del servidor.

Answer (score 1):

en los navegadores modernos puedes usar algo así:

```
new Date().toLocaleString("en-US")
```

Podrías probar de hacer que cada vez que se genere una fecha lo haga con el timeZone del servidor.

Por otro lado en mi opinion la solución más limpia es trabajar siempre con fechas en UTC, ya que es una zona horaria neutra.

Comment: Este código lo único que hace es imprimir la fecha local en un formato específico. Poco tiene que ver con lo que se está preguntando. El autor está preguntando cómo utilizar la fecha del servidor. ¿Cómo sería el código para eso?